# KeyError when using a JSON API

Tags: python, json, api

Using Twitch's API I am trying to make the results from the JSON into an array (I think that's what it's called?)
I get this come up in the console:

`Error Raised: (<class 'KeyError'>, KeyError(0,), <traceback object at 0x04520DA0>)`

And here's the code that defines it all

```
    r = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/runnerbeany'.format(query))
    dat = r.json()
    dat = dat[0]
    data = []
    data.append(dat['display_name'])
    data.append(dat['followers'])
    data.append(dat['game'])
    data.append(dat['logo'])
    data.append(dat['status'])
    data.append(dat['url'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are re-initializing `dat = dat[0]`, rename it with `first_dat = dat[0]`

```
    r = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/runnerbeany'.format(query))
    dat = r.json()
    print dat
    first_dat = dat[0]
    data = []
    data.append(dat['display_name'])
    data.append(dat['followers'])
    data.append(dat['game'])
    data.append(dat['logo'])
    data.append(dat['status'])
    data.append(dat['url'])
```

Comment: So I just remove ```dat = r.json()``` or ```dat = dat[0]```?

Comment: change `dat = dat[0]` to `first_dat = dat[0]`

Comment: edit: thanks for that change - just working out this last error now but thanks for helping! :)